# Make Python Script Executable and Have Parameter

Tags: python, bash, chmod

I made a Python parser for a language I'm making, and I want the script to be executable in the terminal, I've added a shebang, and tried tried the `chmod +x` in the terminal, but I got an error when I typed it:

```
   bash: ./source.py: No file or directory
```

Even though the file exists.
Also, would anyone know how to add parameters/arguments to the command?

Comment: Did you actually copy/paste that line - surely it should be `No such file or directory`?

Comment: You're right, it does have the capital N. I'm sorry, I'm on mobile, it's hard for me to copy. :P

Comment: Obviously check that the filename is correct.  Some older versions of bash will give this message if the interpreter path in the `#!` line is incorrect, so check that as well (the error message changed in later versions).

Comment: GitHub repo: you can check the repo there: https://github.com/bjskistad/jel I need to update it though...

Comment: (Off-topic) in your readme.md: `return` in JavaScript is *not* a function but a keyword; for `print` in Python, it depends on the version (it was a keyword operator but is retconned to a proper function).

Comment: @radlexus Another one of my points, the language Syntax is too loose for JS and PY, those were just my language examples. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell likely does not know to execute the script as a python script.

Add a *shebang* line like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the first line of the file and try again.

To check command line parameters, for simple things you can look in `sys.argv`.  For anything nontrivial, use the `argparse` module instead.

Comment: Redid shebang. Should I try the chmod again?

Comment: It would not be necessary to `chmod +x` again.